# Windows Server 2012 + IIS + NET Framework version error

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET application on my Windows Server 2012 machine.

I followed all the steps that I think were required.

When I try to access the webpage I get this:

[image: Error image]

The "Application Pool" is set to version 4.0.
In the installed programs, NET Framework 4.5 is shown.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

After tried to install this NET Framework 4.5.2 
[NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42642)

I got this:

[image: error net]

Comment: is .net 4.5.2 installed?

Comment: it should be listed in add/remove programs as `Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.2`

Comment: 4.5 only is installed.

Comment: thats the problem. install the right version.

Comment: It's a feature installation or do I need to download the installer from the web?

Comment: install it from the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is straightforward:

> The `targetFramework` attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework.

Install .NET 4.5.2 or later on your server.

Just because you see that "4.5" is installed does not mean 4.5**.2** is installed. See here for version information and release dates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history

- 4.5 with Visual Studio 2012 - 2012-08-15
- 4.5.1 with Visual Studio 2013 - 2013-10-17
- 4.5.2 with Windows 8.1 - 2014-05-05
- 4.6 with Visual Studio 2015 - 2015-07-20

Here is the offline installer for the .NET Framework 4.6.2 which was released in July 2016: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344

Make sure you install all Windows Updates first, and check your Event Logs for any error reports.

Comment: As the error happens during file extraction it's possible your download was corrupted or you have run out of disk space. If this a VM consider creating a new instance from a more recent Windows Server image (such as Server 2016).